# ORA-06550: line 1, column 7 (PL/SQL: Statement ignored) Error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, stored-procedures, procedure

I am getting following error for the stored procedure and not able to understand the issue (must be from db side) While googling, I found similar issues but couldn't get the solution. Can any one help me please find the error in PROCEDURE ??

Error :-

```
18:58:50,281 ERROR [STDERR] java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'SP_DIST_RETAILER_REMAP'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Stored Prodedure(**SP_DIST_RETAILER_REMAP**) :-

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SMAPRD02.SP_DIST_RETAILER_REMAP (    
      i_old_dist_code IN VARCHAR2,
      i_new_dist_code IN VARCHAR2,      
      i_territory_remapping IN NUMBER,
      i_remapping_reason IN VARCHAR2,
      i_trans_doneby_rolename IN VARCHAR2,
      i_trans_doneby_id IN NUMBER,     
      i_trans_dist_rolename IN VARCHAR2, 
      i_trans_ret_rolename IN VARCHAR2,     
      i_activity_type IN VARCHAR2,
      i_ret_list IN V_ARRAY, 
      result OUT VARCHAR2,
      i_o_query OUT VARCHAR2      
)
AS

--i_ret_codes OUT VARCHAR2;

v_dist_count NUMBER;
v_ret_count NUMBER;
v_ret_codes VARCHAR2(10000)  := '';
v_flag VARCHAR2(10) := 'true';
v_trans_id NUMBER;
v_query VARCHAR2(10000);

BEGIN

IF i_territory_remapping = 1 then

SELECT count(*) into v_dist_count FROM tblemployee where EMPCODE = i_new_dist_code and circle_code = (select emp.circle_code
        from tblemployee emp where emp.empcode = i_old_dist_code) and upper(user_type) like upper('%dist%') and upper(ACCESS_TO) in ('SALES','BOTH') and upper(stage) not in (upper('InActive'));

ELSE

SELECT count(*) into v_dist_count FROM tblemployee where EMPCODE = i_new_dist_code and circle_code = (select emp.circle_code from tblemployee emp
   where emp.empcode = i_old_dist_code) and cluster_code = (select emp.cluster_code from tblemployee emp where emp.empcode = i_old_dist_code)
   and upper(user_type) like upper('%dist%') and upper(ACCESS_TO) in ('SALES','BOTH') and upper(stage) not in (upper('InActive'));

END IF; 

IF v_dist_count =0 THEN

result := 'invalid_new_dist_code';

v_flag := 'false';

ELSIF v_dist_count = 1 THEN

SELECT count(*) into v_ret_count FROM tblretailer t where t.DIST_CODE = i_old_dist_code and (upper(t.ACCESS_TO) = 'SALES' or upper(t.ACCESS_TO) = 'BOTH');

--SELECT count(*) into v_ret_count FROM tblretailer t where t.DIST_CODE = i_old_dist_code and upper(t.ACCESS_TO) = 'SALES' and upper(t.stage) in ('APPROVED','INACTIVE');

IF v_ret_count=i_ret_list.count THEN 

   IF i_territory_remapping = 1 THEN

   result := 'no_ret_left';

   v_flag := 'false';

   END IF;

ELSE
    IF i_territory_remapping != 1 THEN

    result := 'ret_left';

    v_flag := 'false';

    END IF;

END IF;


END IF;

IF i_ret_list is null or i_ret_list.count = 0 THEN

    result := 'empty retailers list';

    v_flag := 'false';

END IF;

/*FOR i IN i_ret_list.FIRST .. i_ret_list.LAST
      LOOP


          IF v_ret_codes is null
           THEN          
            v_ret_codes := ''''||i_ret_list(i)||''''; 
          ELSE 

            v_ret_codes  := v_ret_codes||','''||i_ret_list(i)||''''; 

          END IF;        


           IF v_ret_codes is null
           THEN          
            v_ret_codes := i_ret_list(i); 
          ELSE 

            v_ret_codes  := v_ret_codes||','||i_ret_list(i); 

          END IF;     

      END LOOP;

i_ret_codes := v_ret_codes;

v_flag := 'false';
result := 'success';*/

IF v_flag = 'true' THEN

FOR i IN i_ret_list.FIRST .. i_ret_list.LAST
      LOOP


         IF v_ret_codes is null
           THEN          
            v_ret_codes := ''''||i_ret_list(i)||''''; 
          ELSE 

            v_ret_codes  := v_ret_codes||','''||i_ret_list(i)||''''; 

          END IF;               

      END LOOP;

--i_ret_codes := v_ret_codes;


--update tblretailer set dist_code=i_new_dist_code,DIST_ID=to_number(i_new_dist_code),cluster_code=(select cluster_code from tblemployee where empcode = i_new_dist_code),FOSID='',FOS_CODE='',DSR_ID='',DSR_CODE='',LAST_UPDATED_DATE=sysdate where retcode in (v_ret_codes);

v_query := 'update tblretailer set dist_code='||i_new_dist_code||',DIST_ID=to_number('||i_new_dist_code||'),cluster_code=(select cluster_code from tblemployee where empcode = '||i_new_dist_code||'),FOSID='''',FOS_CODE='''',DSR_ID='''',DSR_CODE='''',LAST_UPDATED_DATE=sysdate where retcode in ('||v_ret_codes||')';

execute immediate (v_query);

--i_query :='update tblretailer set dist_code='||i_new_dist_code||',DIST_ID=to_number('||i_new_dist_code||'),cluster_code=(select cluster_code from tblemployee where empcode = '||i_new_dist_code||'),FOSID='',FOS_CODE='',DSR_ID='',DSR_CODE='',LAST_UPDATED_DATE=sysdate where retcode in ('||v_ret_codes||');';

insert into TBL_TRANSFER_SUP_MASTER(MASTER_ID,TRANS_ID,TRANS_DONEBY_ROLENAME,TRANS_DONEBY_ID,TRANS_FROM_ROLENAME,TRANS_FROM,TRANS_TO_ROLENAME,TRANS_TO,ACTIVITY_CODE,TRANS_DATE,TRANSFER_REASON,LAST_UPDATED_DATE)
                 values(SUP_MASTER_TRANS_ID_SEQ.nextval,SUP_MASTER_TRANS_ID_SEQ.nextval,i_trans_doneby_rolename,i_trans_doneby_id,i_trans_dist_rolename,i_old_dist_code,i_trans_dist_rolename,i_new_dist_code,'101',sysdate,i_remapping_reason,sysdate) return TRANS_ID into v_trans_id;


FOR i IN i_ret_list.FIRST .. i_ret_list.LAST
      LOOP

      insert into TBL_TRANSFER_SUP_DTLS(DTLS_ID,TRANS_ID,TRANS_ON_ROLENAME,TRANS_ON_ID,LAST_UPDATED_DATE)
             values(SUP_DTLS_ID_SEQ.nextval,v_trans_id,i_trans_ret_rolename,i_ret_list(i),sysdate);


      END LOOP;

IF SQL%ROWCOUNT>0 THEN

result := 'success';

ELSE

result := 'failure';

END IF;

--update tblstock set NEW_DIST_CODE_REMAP=i_new_dist_code,REMAP_DATE=sysdate,LAST_UPDATED_DATE=sysdate where (DIST_CODE=i_old_dist_code or NEW_DIST_CODE_REMAP=i_old_dist_code) and RET_CODE in (v_ret_codes);      

v_query := 'update tblstock set NEW_DIST_CODE_REMAP='||i_new_dist_code||',REMAP_DATE=sysdate,LAST_UPDATED_DATE=sysdate where (DIST_CODE='||i_old_dist_code||' or NEW_DIST_CODE_REMAP='||i_old_dist_code||') and RET_CODE in ('||v_ret_codes||')';     

execute immediate (v_query);

i_o_query := v_query;

insert all into TBL_ACTIVITY_LOG (LOG_ID,TRANS_ID,ACTIVITY_DONEBY_ROLENAME,ACTIVITY_DONEBY_ID,ACTIVITY_REFERENCE_ID,ACTIVITY_CODE,ACTIVITY_DATE)
                values(ACTIVITY_LOG_TRANS_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,ACTIVITY_LOG_TRANS_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,i_trans_doneby_rolename,i_trans_doneby_id,v_trans_id,
                act_code,sysdate) select log_config.ACTIVITY_CODE act_code from TBL_ACTIVITY_LOG_CONFIG log_config  
               where upper(log_config.ACTIVITY_TYPE)= upper(i_activity_type);

END IF;

END;
/
```

Java Code :-

```
try{            
            if(ret_list.size()>0)
                ret_code = ret_list.toArray();
             con = ConnectionManager.getDirectConnection();
             ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(PropertyLoader.RET_SECONDARY_V_ARRAY,con);
             ARRAY array_to_pass = new ARRAY( descriptor,con, ret_code );
             cstmt = con.prepareCall("{ call SP_DIST_RETAILER_REMAP(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
             cstmt.setString(1,old_dist_code.trim());
             cstmt.setString(2,new_dist_code.trim());
             if(territory_remapping)            
             cstmt.setInt(3,1);
             else
             cstmt.setInt(3,2);          
             cstmt.setString(4,remapping_reason);
             cstmt.setString(5,userVO.getRolename().trim());
             cstmt.setInt(6,userVO.getEmpid());
             cstmt.setString(7,PropertyLoader.DISTRIBUOTR_ROLENAME);
             cstmt.setString(8,PropertyLoader.RETAILER_ROLENAME);
             cstmt.setString(9,PropertyLoader.ACTIVITY_TYPES_RETAILER_REMAPPING);
             cstmt.setArray(10,array_to_pass);
             cstmt.registerOutParameter(11,Types.VARCHAR);
             cstmt.registerOutParameter(12,Types.VARCHAR);
             /*cstmt.registerOutParameter(13,Types.VARCHAR);*/
             cstmt.execute();
             status = cstmt.getString(11);
             System.out.println("Remap Update Query  "+cstmt.getString(12));
             //System.out.println(cstmt.getString(13));

        }
```

Comment: The error text seems to indicate you're using an incorrect number or type of arguments when calling the SP. This could be related to how you bind the in/out parameters to the call java-side. Can you show how are you using it?

Comment: @XaviLópez
Java Code added in the question sir.

Comment: Is `RET_SECONDARY_V_ARRAY` resolving to the same `V_ARRAY` the procedure is using? They have to be the same SQL-level type declaration; different types (even if they are declared identically) would throw this error I believe.

Comment: I have doubts over ARRAY object used in the code. Collection.ToArray[] returns Object[] and depends on generics. I am not sure if this array datatype and V_ARRAY datatype match each other. Can you share the definition of V_ARRAY and show the datatype of ret_code.

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan
public static String RET_SECONDARY_V_ARRAY = "";
ret_code varchar2(null)

Comment: @AlexPoole
Yes both have same declaration...

Comment: @Rajan - different types with the same declaration isn't enough, they have to be the exact same type. Can you add the type declaration for `V_ARRAY` and the value of `PropertyLoader.RET_SECONDARY_V_ARRAY` at runtime - it isn't really empty, surely? Essentially `RET_SECONDARY_V_ARRAY` has to be set to `"V_ARRAY"`. Just trying to establish if that is the case, it might not be your problem but it looks suspicious to me.

Comment: @AbhijithNagarajan 
Sir I've found problem of problem, While executing the query from toad I dont understand what to enter in HIGHLIGHTED area as its an array. The procedure name is same as posted above in the Question. Kindly refer the image attached in below URL.
i.imgur.com/L2uug2a.gif

Comment: I mean how to insert values in Type = TABLE !!

Answer (score 0):

If the value stored in `PropertyLoader.RET_SECONDARY_V_ARRAY` is not `"V_ARRAY"`, then you are using different types; even if they are declared identically (e.g. both are `table of number`) this will not work.

You're hitting [this data type compatibility restriction](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/composites.htm#LNPLS99918):

> You can assign a collection to a collection variable only if they have
>   the same data type. Having the same element type is not enough.

You're trying to call the procedure with a parameter that is a different type to the one it's expecting, which is what the error message is telling you.

Comment: I have two databases having same table structure, I tried with another db and its working fine, but while connecting to this db I am getting this error. Any clue ?? –

Comment: The clue is that you seem to be hitting different table types. Please show the type declarations (on both databases) and the parameter value. Otherwise it's just guesswork.

Comment: Sir I've found problem of problem,
While executing the query from toad I dont understand what to enter in HIGHLIGHTED area as its an array. The procedure name is same as posted above in the Question.
http://i.imgur.com/L2uug2a.gif
Kindly refer the image attached in below URL.

Comment: @Rajan - you're trying to call the procedure from Toad? You'd need to declare a `V_ARRAY` object and populate and pass that (or pass null) in the proc call. You still haven't said how that type is defined.

Comment: Sir I am not a professional DBA. I am a java developer, So not getting what you are trying to say.

Comment: well I am able to execute the query now and found that there is no problem with the query, now what should I look for ???

Comment: @Rajan - I've said several times that you need to see what `RET_SECONDARY_V_ARRAY` is pointing to. Please confirm it is set to `V_ARRAY`. It would still be helpful if you showed how that type is defined.

Comment: I am not getting in which context you are askinf the type of it, can you please elaborate ??

Comment: `V_ARRAY` is a user-defined type. At some point someone has created it, with something like `create type v_array as table of number`. I'm asking to see that command. You can do `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TYPE', 'V_ARRAY') from dual` to see it if you are not sure. The value of `RET_SECONDARY_V_ARRAY` is also critical; why will you not say what that is?

Comment: Sir, Problem solved, I was connecting with the third database I had in file.properties file, connected with right db and solved. By the way the SP was not available in that third db thats why I was getting the issue. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The **procedure** which you are using is should be **properly declared** in the place which you are using it. For an example if it is under a **user** and in a **package** then it should be in that order. The **username, package and procedurename**.